# How can I programatically attach recovery email when creating user's e-mail address

Tags: google-apps, google-admin-sdk, google-directory-api

I'm creating an application that creates google apps accounts using a WWW application. User for which we are creating that account provides his personal e-mail address that will be set as an recovery e-mail address (it really makes sense in this case!).

I couldn't find a way to set user's recovery e-mail address. Is there a way to do this programatically.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like the phone number used for recovery and Login Challenges, I don't believe it's possible to set a recovery email address for a user upon provisioning (via the Apps APIs). This needs to be something the user or users do manually once they gain access to their account as a best practice.