# Google Apps Provisioning (Admin API): Can I programmatically set a recovery email or phone number?

Tags: google-apps, provisioning, google-admin-sdk, google-directory-api

Is it possible to programmatically set a specific email or phone number as an email/phone number to use for recovery?  Our provisioning process is currently an automated script using the Google Admin SDK that creates users based on a CSV.

Thanks for the insight.

Apparently this has been asked before in similar fashion, but it's a bit old and doesn't talk about phone numbers: [How can I programatically attach recovery email when creating user's e-mail address](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25950828/how-can-i-programatically-attach-recovery-email-when-creating-users-e-mail-addr)

Answer (score 2):

No, unfortunately this currently isn't possible using the API.

Comment: Right.  I mean it makes sense for fairly obvious security reasons, just doing some due diligence.  Thanks.